# Painting Rainbows

Tags: arduino, led, rgb

I was painting my 2 year old's daughter's bedroom yesterday, she handed me a paint brush and asked me to paint her a rainbow.

I could paint her a rainbow, using paint, but I don't have many colour and my wife would go spare.  I do have just enough electronics experience to be dangerous and I'm thinking it would be a nice project to paint her a rainbow using light.

1) what would be the best approach for creating a nice vivid rainbow, (but not necessarily mega-bright, I can limit it's appearance to bedtime).  Can I use a prism with an artificial light source to split the light into a rainbow, or is the spectrum of incandescents and LED's not as complete as Sunlight (I suspect this is the case)

2) Assuming the best option would be 7 LED's (probably RGB LED's each set for ROYGBIV perhaps in the 3w-5w range) what ideas do people have for making an aesthetic and impressive (to a 2 year old) rainbow on a white wall?

I appreciate that this might be a less technical question than is usually asked here, I hope that doesn't offend anyone.  If I have left out any detail, please mention it and I'll add it in.  (I'm not to bothered by budget, £50($75) would be my limit, I have good knowledge of AVR and and Arduino programming. I have also successfully made my own toner transfer PCB's)

Thanks
Jim

Comment: I know you want to do-it-yourself, but my niece has [one of these](http://www.amazon.com/BestDealUSA-Rainbow-LED-Projector-Decoration/dp/B005JW2JFS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337862685&sr=8-1) and it works nicely. Perhaps you could leverage their design for your own device.

Answer (score 5):

A prism with a halogen filament bulb will probably do an OK job as a light source.

Many ideas in the images below - each links to a relevant page.

A [diffraction grating and slit](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=diffraction+grating&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=6xS5T5XrA7G6iAfCptSFCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CE8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=864) can be used instead of a prism.

[An unused DVD makes a fair diffraction grating](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=diffraction+grating&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvnsb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=6xS5T5XrA7G6iAfCptSFCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CE8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=864#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=diffraction+grating+dvd&oq=diffraction+grating+dvd&aq=f&aqi=g2g-m1g-S7&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5j0i24l7.68205.69062.0.69335.4.4.0.0.0.0.390.771.3-2.2.0...0.0.XxhSlj_Oytg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=aa652db8b45e02c2&biw=1536&bih=864)

---

[Note: The links are intended to be to pages of images which are linked to text, and **not** to pages of text directly. Please do not edit to remove this functionality. This is a useful and informative way of accessing the information as the images give a good idea of what to expect on each site AND the links will not go dead because of what they are.]

Answer (score 2):

for $75 you should be able to get a few small cans of paint of the various colors.  You don't need a gallon of each, just a small can of each will do.  That will be cheaper, look nicer, and quicker than a electronic solution.  It also works without power.

Maybe you can set up something with mirrors and a prism to split sunlight, which of course only works when the sun is in the right place.  Incandscent light is quite weak in the shorter wavelengths, and other artificial light will have bands and gaps at various wavelenghts.  You can get a few different colors of LEDs, but they will be sparse at the short wavelengths too.  Pure LEDs have a narrow spectrum, so will show up as lines thru a prism, not a nice spread out color.  The LEDs that use phosphor re-emission will have a bit broader spectrum, but it will still be mostly a collection of lines.

Personally, I'd go for the paint.

Comment: you've not met my wife ;)  It's not an option to use paint, trust me on that one!

Answer (score 1):

A prism and a small incandescent light bulb will do it. An incandescent lightbulb will have roughly the same spectrum as sunlight at sunset.

If you prefer LED the easiest would be to use a single high CRI white LED and a prism. You are correct that LED's generally don't have not have as even spectrum as sunlight. A good white LED will have a reasonably broad specter and is probably better than dealing with multiple single color LEDs.

CRI is a rough measure of the color quality of white light and the higher the CRI, the better the color rendering is. Something [like this](http://no.farnell.com/osram/lcw-cqdp-cc-kqks-5l7n-1-k/oslon-150-ssl-colour-champ/dp/2078823?Ntt=LCW%20CQDP.CC-KQKS-5L7N) will give you a a CRI of 90 or so which is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

A nice and easy alternative may be an RGB LED rotating throught the color range, creating a rainbow in time instead of in space.

Another way is to use 3 LED, again R, G and B, and use a shield with a slot for each one, creating overlapping stripes. You should be able to fuse the stripes and create a sort of rainbow.